# Get variables from one PHP form to another

Tags: php

New to php, don't have code for this, just a question.
I have a form that accepts user input, then validates the input.
input.php
if invalid, it repeats the input page.
if valid, it proceeds to another 
process.php

What i don't understand is how to get the user data from input.php to process.php
I prefer to do this without storing the data in a database or file. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` variable..

Comment: If you are accessing with HTML form, you can pass by POST request. Otherwise you can use SESSION varaiables. Just go through about PHP Sessions.

Comment: `http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php` refer this, to know to do it with session..

Comment: @user2168066 please check my answer it will help you more.

Comment: “proceeds to another `process.php`”: Proceed how? If you redirect the client browser, this is something completely different from if you [`require`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) the other file on the server side. In the former case, you'll have to have some form of persistence, whereas in the latter case you can simply use global variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SESSION for storing the values on server or pass the values through URL using GET.

Please refer the php manual to have an idea on using [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) and [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score -1):

On process.php just print the data using `$_POST ,$_GET or $_REQUEST` you will get all data in array which you processed through the form.
Eg. index.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="process.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

process.php

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br>
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.

</body>
</html>
```